# Visible User ID in Address Bar

Tags: security, url, web

Currently, to pass a user id to the server on certain views I use the raw user id.

```
http://example.com/page/12345 //12345 Being the users id
```

Although there is no real security risk in my specific application by exposing this data, I can't help but feeling a little dirty about it. What is the proper solution? Should I somehow be disguising the data?

Maybe a better way to propose my question is to ask what the standard approach is. Is it common for applications to use user id's in plain view if it's not a security risk? If it is a security risk how is it handled? I'm just looking for a point in the right direction here.

Comment: Is it a problem if a user can change the URL to view another user's page, such as `/page/12346`?

Comment: Not really. The pages are public. That being said i'm not crazy about someone being able to just increase the number one by one trolling around and for lack of a better word being annoying. I'd like to somehow disguise the id, but not sure of the proper approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with that. Lots of sites do it. For instance, Stack Overflow users can be enumerated using URLs of the form:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/users/123456
```

Using a normalized form of the user's name in the URL, either in conjunction with the ID or as an alternative to it, may be a nicer solution, though, e.g:

```
http://example.com/user/yourusername

http://example.com/user/12345/yourusername
```

If you go with the former, you'll need to ensure that the normalized username is set up as a unique key in your user database.

If you go with the latter, you've got a choice: if the normalized username in the database doesn't match the one in the URL, you can either redirect to the correct URL (like Stack Overflow does), or return a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to duskwuff's great suggestion to use the username instead of the ID itself, you could use [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) instead of integers. They are 128-bit in length so infeasible to enumerate, and also avoid disclosing exactly how many users you have. As an added benefit, your site is future proofed against user id limits if it becomes massively popular.

For example, with integer ids, an attacker could find out the largest user_id on day one, and come back in a week or months time and find what the largest user_id is now. They can continually do this to monitor the rate of growth on your site - perhaps not a biggie for your example - but many organisations consider this sort of information commercially sensitive. Also helps avoid social engineering, e.g. makes it significantly harder for an attacker to email you asking to reset their password "because I've changed email providers and I've forgotten my old password but I remember my user id!". Give an attack an inch and they'll run a mile.

I prefer to use [Version/Type 4 (Random) UUIDs](http://www.uuidgenerator.net/version4), however you could also use Version/Type 5 (SHA-1-based) so you could go UUID.fromName(12345) and get a UUID derived from the integer value, which is useful if you want to migrate existing data and need to update a bunch of foreign key values. Most major languages support UUIDs natively or are included in popular libraries (C & C++), although some database software might require some tweaking - I've used them with postgres and myself and are easy transitions.

The downside is UUIDs are significantly longer and not memorable, but it doesn't sound like you need the ability for the user to type in the URLs manually. You do also need to [check if the UUID already exists](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/130261/uuid-collisions) when creating a user, and if it does, just keep generating until an unused UUID is found - in practice given the size of the numbers, using Version 4 Random UUIDs you will have a better chance at winning the lottery than dealing with a collision, so it's not something that will impact performance etc.

Example URL: http://example.com/page/4586A0F1-2BAD-445F-BFC6-D5667B5A93A9